# Excel reports to database sql server 2005

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, excel, import

I am being given excel sheet daily and want to upload them to an existing database with the exact same column names, i wanted to do this in sql server 2005, but then i thought it would be easier to just creat an asp.net program that could do this autmatically, that way the managers could do it them selves.

would i use a bulk insert?

and how would i import the excel sheet into a datatable?

**Edit:**
I got the first part to work

```
handling time 
1:12:53
1:06:29
0:10:58
0:13:33
1:15:45
0:41:19
```

that is one of my columns in my excel sheet (hh:mm:ss)

however when i do the bulk copy into a varchar field

i get

```
12/30/1899 1:12:53 AM
12/30/1899 1:06:29 AM
12/30/1899 12:10:58 AM
12/30/1899 12:13:33 AM
12/30/1899 1:15:45 AM
12/30/1899 12:41:19 AM
```

Comment: Why not make that column as text in the excel sheet. Right now, it is date Field in your excel sheet, that's why it is converting to Datetime when we query from Excel.

Comment: i tried that is there a way to do it in the sql

Comment: when you selecting data from Excel, Select Convert(Varchar,FieldName), try something like.. but I am not sure.

Comment: hmm the problem with changing the field to a text was it converted it into a decimal wierd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I would suggest you to use SqlBulkCopy

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
            DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
            DbCommand selectCommand = factory.CreateCommand();
            selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ColumnNames FROM [Sheet1$]";
            DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            selectCommand.Connection = connection;
            adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dtbl);

            if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
{
 using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destConnection))
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ColumnName", "ColumnName");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ColumnName", "ColumnName");

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DBTableName";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtblNew);
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks i got it to work but i am facing one problem maybe you can help